# Java If block with multiple statements

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a question about `IF` clause in **Java**.
I have and expression:

```
if ((someObject != null & connectedToTheInternet) || operate) {
    // some action
}
```

Is my logic right: if `someObject != null` equals to **true** and `connectedToTheInternet` equals **false** then we have `(someObject != null & connectedToTheInternet)` equals **false** and then we have the following block:

```
if (false || operate) {
   // some action
}
```

And if `operate` equals **true** then `// some action` will be triggered?

Comment: `if ((someObject != null && connectedToTheInternet) || operate) {` is the write statement.

Comment: Yes. It will be executed because one condition is true.

Comment: Yes. This is bitwise AND operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a first note: logical AND operator is "&&" and not just "&" (bitwise AND).

Following, your answer is YES... JVM will run conditions following your thinking.

By the way, I suggest you to read something abot short-circuit of these operators: it can be interesting if you are learning.

For example if you have `if (a && (b || c)` and `a==false`, then JVM won't evaluate `b` or `c` conditions because `false && ...` will be always false.

The same in the case of `if (a || b || c && d)`: if `a==true` then JVM will ignore the other parts and consider it as true because `true || ....` will be always true.

Comment: The result is what you are saying, but just "&" is formally defined as a bitwise operator, not as boolean operator

Comment: && is so called Conditional-AND, & is bitwise AND. Both are AND operators.

Comment: no correct, test yourself ;) & is bitwise and, but also and with without-short-circuit

Comment: @A.Panzer We are dealing with someone is moving his first step; I think in this case is most important to provide basic information... and not to confuse him :)

Comment: @MrTux I agree with you... I  know the result is the same... :) I'm just saying that the question is about logical operator and formally the java and logical operator is && and not the bitwise and (because this is a question by a java newbye and I won't confuse him)

Comment: We shouldn't confuse him using wrong terminology ;)

Comment: @A.Panzer Excuse me... what is my error? We never stop to learn :)

Comment: @Pierpaolo Cira && is not the only AND operator. Both operators could be called AND operators.

Comment: @A.Panzer I think you're right: it wasn't so clear in my first response, but only in my first response. I edited my original answer to highlight this aspect.

Comment: @Pierpaolo Cira Now it looks fine. Congrats you answer is accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. if-clauses are evaluated from left to right. If no parenthesis are used, `&&` has precedence, even higher precedence has `!` (not) - similar to multiplication (AND), addition (OR) and negative numbers (-) in math (e.g. "A && (B || C) != A && B || C == (A && B) ||C") - I recommend to use parenthesis if you are unsure. This makes it possible to combine `!= null` checks and calls to methods in the same if statement (e.g., `if (object!=null && object.dosomething())`).

Btw. there is a difference between `&` and `&&` ([short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)), when `&` is used, the second condition gets evaluated even if the first is `false` already. When `&&` is used, Java doesn't check the second condition if the first one is `false` as the whole term cannot be true anymore - this is only important when the second condition is not a boolean variable but a method (which gets called or not -> [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29); this "skipping" is called short-circuit). Same for `||` and `|` where the second operator might not get evaluated if the first is already `true` (in case of `||`).

Normally only `||`and `&&` are used.

Just for completeness: `&` is also the bitwise AND operator in Java.

Comment: Thank's for adding your last note after our discussion... ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (false || operate) {  
   // some action
}
```

If operate true then if block executing.